# SOQL record with highest value, GROUP BY not working

Tags: soql, group-by

We have an object called "Compensation__c". This object contains the compensation a partner receives for selling a "Product2".

"Compensation__c" has a start date. Before this date this compensation is not valid yet. A "Product2" can have multiple compensation records scheduled in the future, so today I will get €1,- and I might get €2,- tomorrow for this same product and €1,50 next week.

I need to create a SOQL query which returns the current compensation record for a selection of products.

```
SELECT Id, Product__c, PartnerCompensation__c FROM Compensation__c WHERE CompensationType__c = :compensation AND StartDate__c <= TODAY AND Product__c IN :productIds
```

How do I select the most recent active compensation? I want to group by Product__c, but then all other fields must be aggregated as well. I do not want an average or max compensation, I want the actual compensation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parent-child subquery (a.k.a. a Left Outer Join) to associate `Compensation__c` records to their related `Product2` record.

This will allow you to filter `Compensation__c` records as you wish, using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to grab just the most recent, appropriate record.

```
[SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT Id, PartnerCompensation__c 
        FROM Compensations__r 
        WHERE CompensationType__c = :compensation AND StartDate__c <= TODAY 
        ORDER BY StartDate__c DESC 
        LIMIT 1) 
 FROM Product2 
 WHERE Id IN :productIds]
```

`Compensations__r` is the child relationship name (which you should be able to see/verify by looking at the definition of your Product__c lookup field).

A subquery returns a `List<SObject>` embedded in the resulting `Product2` records, and you'd access the `Compensation__c` records like this

```
for(Product2 prod :<the query>){
    // Subqueries result in fully-fledged SObject records
    // Once you pull a record out of the list, you can use it just like you would
    //   any other SObject.
    Compensation__c mostRecent = prod.Compensations__r[0];

    system.debug(mostRecent.PartnerCompensation__c);
}
```